# When do millimeters and inches line up nicely?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let the set of all **inch measures** $\bigl( \mathbb{IMS} \bigr)$ be the set of **unitized real numbers** constructed from the set of strings $\begin{Bmatrix} f(x) + “ \,\,\,\,\mathtt{inch(es)}” : x \in \dfrac{n}{2^p} \\ \text{ where } n \leq 2^p \text{ and } n, p \in \mathbb{N} \bigcup \{0\} \end{Bmatrix} $.

Specifically, we define a unitized decimal number to be class having two fields:

> - a value field taken from $\mathbb{R}$
> - a unit field, which is a string such as “inches” or “feet”

For example, if $\mathtt{obj}$ is an element of the set of all inch measures, then maybe we have:

> $\mathtt{obj.unit} = “inch(es)"$
>
> $\mathtt{obj.value} = “5.5"$

$f$ is a function.

When you put a number $x$ inside of function $f$ and turn the crank, then out pops a string.

For example, $f(0.25) = “ 1/4 inch(es)"$

One example of an inch measure is “1/16 inch(es)"

Most questions without a little LaTeX an mathematical maturity demonstrated get deleted. Thus, we introduced a the notation and a few pseudo-formalisms.

My primary question is, what is the set of $\mathbb{IM} \in \mathbb{IMS}$ such that after converting inches to millimeters, the measurment in millimeters is almost a whole number?

More formally, let $g$ be a function which accepts unitized real numbers in inches as input and outputs a unitized real number in millimeters.

When is g(x) less the floor of g(x) less than 0.1 millimeters?

After converting inches to millimeters the result is less than one tenth of a millimeters away from a whole number of millimeters.

Comment: This seems to be a lot just to say "What are non-negative integers $n,p$ with $n \leq 2^p$ such that $25.4n/2^p - \lfloor 25.4n/2^p\rfloor < 0.1$?"

Comment: @BrianMoehring you are correct Brian. We should edit the original question and replace the text with your more succinct wording.

Comment: An inch is 25.4mm. what else is to be said?

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a comment, but it's a bit too long to fit in the comment box.

You might find the theory of [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20continued%20fraction,another%20reciprocal%2C%20and%20so%20on.) to be interesting, with particular emphasis on the [convergents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents) of the continued fraction expansion of a real number.

The idea is that for each real number $r$ there is a special sequence of rational numbers $p_n/q_n$ called the *convergents* of $r$, such that for each of these numbers we have $\left| r - \frac{p_n}{q_n}\right| < \frac{c}{q_n^2}$ (for some constant $c$). Intuitively this says that $p_n/q_n$ is an unusually good approximation to $r$: if one fixes an integer $q$ one would expect to find an integer $p$ such that $\left| r - \frac{p}{q}\right| < \frac{1/2}{q}$, so to get that denominator to be $q^2$ would be unusual.

Now take $r$ to be the ratio of 1 millimeter to 1 inch. Then for each convergent $p_n/q_n$, $p_n$ inches is unusually close to $q_n$ millimeters.

Comment: The ratio of millimetres to inches is rational: an inch is exactly 25.4mm. So the beautiful theory of continued fractions is not relevant here.

Comment: Hah, I did not think that was true... I seem to be about 75 years out of date, and since I'm only 66, it's no excuse :-/

Answer (score 0):

To convert inches to millimetres, multiply by 25.4. No approximation is required. See [the Wikipedia article on the inch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inch). To convert inches to millimeters, do the same, as US inches are the same as Imperial (UK) inches and the [SI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) appear to accept both the UK and US spellings of metre/meter as meaning the same thing.